# Vector2.MoveTowards -- Move To Target Position and Some More

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I almost created game but there is one thing which is hard for me. I want to move player to target and some more.

The red dot is the goal, but I want to move the player to the goal and a little further.

P.S
If the player goes to the right then I want him to reach the goal and a little further to the right

same to the left, top, bottom

Look Attachment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7htWB.jpg
Red dot is a target but i want player move to target and else more on the facing side (green dot)

i tried something like move forward but i dont have any idea.

```
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, (speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
    //Mob have "Player" TAG (Player is not a player) |Targeting is fine|
```

Comment: How exactly do you move left,right,top or down?

Comment: Mob spawning when previous mob is dead. One by One.

When Player see new mob, Player Move into him. but only one i need to move little further.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an offset value

```
// ajdust this in the inspector
public float offset = 0.1f;
```

and than add it to the position in the direction from the player to the target. As Foggzie mentioned this might not be a copy-past-able code yet since there might occure some hickups. To atleast prevent that the player turn around after overshooting the target and move back and forth you could use a setter method to get the direction only once:

```
public float offset;
public float threshold = 0.0001f;
public float speed;

private GameObject target;
private Vector3 direction;
private Vector3 targetPosition;

public void SetTarget(GameObject newTarget)
{
    target = newTarget;

    // adding the offset in that direction
    targetPosition = target.transform.position + direction * offset;

    // direction from the player to the target
    direction = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (!target) return;

    // make Player overshoot the target by offset
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, (speed * Time.deltaTime));

    // stop if target is reached
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) <= threshold)
    {
        target = null;
    }
}
```

I don't know when and how you change the target so currently it doesn't limit the player movement to only X and Y like in your pictures ... but you would than do e.g.

```
// Note that 'transform' is a built-in property of 'GameObject' and you shouldn't use `GetComponent` for it
SetTarget(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform);
```

---

[image]

Comment: You'll have to make sure setting `direction` and `targetPosition` aren't happening in the update loop and instead only happen whenever a new target is selected.  Otherwise, the frame after you step past `target.transform.position` (and if your step is smaller than `offset`), your `direction` and `targetPosition` variables will reverse and the game object will just wiggle back and fourth forever. There's also the very rare but possible case were `direction` is evaluated when the object is directly on top of the target. This will result in `direction` being `Vector.zero` and it won't move at all